# Merge two dataframes with pandas by ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes/csv files and I'm trying to merge them by ID.

df1:

[image: Dataframe1]

df2:

[image: Dataframe2]

I'm trying to do this:

```
df3 = (pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='leg_id', right_on='leg', how='inner'))
```

I want the see all the data from df2 where id its id_leg on df1 and want to see also the data from df1 probably it would repeat in every entrance of df2 because its 1:M

Some advice?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I found the problem,i was doing replace to with space... so the id's dont match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *merge* has such a downside that both *leg_id* and *leg*
are contained in the result (with the same content).

Maybe a better option is to:

- Set the index in *df1* to *leg_id*.
- Set the index in *df2* to *leg*.
- Join both DataFrames (now on their indices).

So far, the result has index (taken from *leg_id* and *leg*) but
**with no name**. To change it into an "ordinary", named column, you can:

- Rename the index (e.g. to *leg*).
- Reset the index (actually just this operation changes it onto an
  "ordinary" column).

The code to do it is:

```
df1.set_index('leg_id').join(df2.set_index('leg'), how='inner')\
    .rename_axis(index='leg').reset_index()
```

The advantage of this solution over *merge* is that the index column
occurs only once.